# Android Mobile Backend Starter fail with 404 not found... some times

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend

Last afternoon I created a project and deployed the mobile backend started. I edited the client code and sucessfully did some data insertion.

Some time (hours) after, I changed the cliend code again and the insertion failed with the error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
```

As I didn't did any substantial change in the code I concluded that the error was on the app engine side so I redeployed the project and that solved the problem. The insertions came through again.

This morning I was back with the 404 error. This time redeploying didn't work.

The error log I get in the app engine is:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiConfigException: <Entity [GoogleCloudEndpointConfiguration("EndpointV1")]:
    clientIds = null
    audiences = null
>
.audiences was not of type String or List<String>.
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:451)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any idea what is happening and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: I haven't been able to do a single insert with the Guestbook Activity sample. Error: A toast with this error shows up in my android app: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found Not Found. (I am using Android Studio)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not completely understand what is going on, but I found a way to get rid of the 404 errors on the client side, which are caused by the App Engine side not responding. The errors reported in the app engine logs are talking about audience and client ids for the app. Those are the values you set when you configure authentication for "Secured by Client Ids".

[image: Mobile Backend Settings page]

I found that if I put in some placeholder string values in there, saved, and then went back to "Open (for development use only)" and saved again, the app engine would no longer have config errors and would response to the client Android app.

At the moment I am only to the place where entries are made in the Guestbook data. But this definitely got me started again. I am hoping that if I set up authentication completely that the problem will not come back.

Comment: Mate, I'm almost break in tears. This problem was driving me crazy for weeks and I know I would never guess that solution.

It works... I just wanna buy you a beer and give you a hug :')
(Seriously, you made my day)

Comment: Glad it helped. I finally got the whole Google IO demo for Geek Serendipity working, which was where I ran into the problem. For others looking for a good example, check Brad Abrams' blog post: http://bradabrams.com/2013/05/google-io-2013-session-overview-from-nothing-to-nirvana-in-minutes-cloud-backend-for-your-android-application-building-geek-serendipity/

Comment: #Bill Lahti do you have an Android Studio project of there that you can post in GitHub, cos this is driving me nuts...

Comment: @Anthony. Sorry, no. I have been using Eclipse.

Comment: I believe the issue comes from the fact that the instance fails without these values. Also, with the recent changes in the console this is not readily available anymore; see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18599404/549510

Comment: I know this is odd seeing how its nearly a year later.  But where can I find this screen?

Comment: I think it might be the default page for the deployed app. If not the default, it is your appspot url plus "admin/configure.jsp".

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, the error went away after redeploying the backend app on cloud console.

Comment: I tried that but "kind of" didn't work. 
Some times it works after one or too redeploys. Sometimes don't. All times I get a bit more crazy.

Comment: This worked for me, but I did try Bill Lahti's fix above too, so I don't know if the combination of both sorted it...

Answer (score 1):

I found that after redeploy a new version is created, instead of reseting the default one.
When selecting this new version as 'default' everything worked as expected.

Select instance as default at (Main / Version):

```
https://appengine.google.com/adminlogs?&app_id=<project_id>
```

Check at:

```
https://<project_id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect fix.

Log on to the app engine. Click on Instances on the left hand side.
At the right bottom , you will see an option as "Shutdown"

Click on Shutdown. (Shutdown is not just shutdown. Its a restart).

The instance gets started in 10-12 seconds. Note : During these 10-12 seconds , the app engine is not accessible. So, if your app is live , your cloud will not work for these 10-12 seconds.

Refresh the page after 10 seconds and make sure you see the Shutdown option . This means your instance is restarted.

Now , retry and it will work. Send me email to jscript12@gmail.com if you still have questions

Comment: Check the acepted answer provided by @Bill Lathi. It worked for me and I never had the same problem again.

Comment: Yes , I did what was suggested by @Bill Lathi that but that didnot help. The one I posted helped me. At this moment , I am not sure what exactly was causing this issue.