# Google app Engine's sample android app, throwing exceptions

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My GAE sample android app was working all right till yesterday!

I did not do any changes to the client app except in Consts.java added my project ID.

Now every time i try to insert (i mean send message) following exceptions are throw

```
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905): error: 
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905): Not Found
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:314)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1060)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackend.insert(CloudBackend.java:111)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync.access$0(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:87)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
06-06 09:42:59.905: I/CloudBackend(1905):   at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:428)
```

Comment: means The user does not have read access to a file, or the file does not exist.

Comment: I dont think so. Because this worked for me when I ran the same code for the first day. I hope this is something to do with the server. And also as i have mentioned, I have not done any changes to the code.

Comment: I had a similar error with Mobile Backend App and the solution was to redeploy the server and reinstall the client app. Sometimes I must repeat the operation twice (I don't know the cause of the problem), but I hope my comment could help you.

Comment: @laviniux I tried it. It is not helping :(

Comment: I Had the same problem and found [this solution][1] usefull.





  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957391/android-mobile-backend-starter-fail-with-404-not-found-some-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this.

It seems like there is a bug in app engine that every time when your app generates a new version of itself by you redeploying it or so, it forgets to make the latest deployment as default under app engine console.
Follow the steps to make it default:

1. go to [appengine console](https://appengine.google.com/)
2. Open your project
3. On the left hand side, open up Main -> Versions
4. Make the most latest version as default by clicking the radio button beside it.

**That's it I hope**

Comment: I have the same issue, but the steps above did not resolve it.  good tip though