# Variety of errors in Mobile Backend Starter Sample app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I set up the Mobile Backend Starter Sample app from the Google Cloud console. The app with the android client one can use as a chat client. 
When I set it up for the first time I got a 404 NotFound, JsonParseException.

I solved this by ReDeploying 2-3 times.

Then it worked for 5-6 hours after which I was faced with 503 Service Unavailable 503 error.
I tried redeploying  but I am back to the 404 NotFound error.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Yes I have changed the PROJECT_ID in my Android client code.

Is ReDeploying again and again the only solution ?

Comment: you should really share some appengine log for someone to help you.

Comment: Hey I Have exact same problem :( I have posts related to this with complete logcat. Unfortunately nobody replied to this yet !
503 Error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026044/google-app-engine-sample-app-throwing-503

404 Error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959063/google-app-engines-sample-android-app-throwing-exceptions

Comment: Thanks for sharing your logcat logs. The logs which I see are exactly the same. I solve my problem with redeploying, which works till about 4-5 hours sometimes upto 2-3 days if I am lucky. Hope someone who knows this can help us.

Comment: I hade the same problem and the splied answer worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957391/android-mobile-backend-starter-fail-with-404-not-found-some-times