# Mobile Backend Starter Missing from Cloud Console

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I wanted to try out cloud-connected Android app as per this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/getting_started

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5u_Owtbfew

However after creating the project in Cloud Console I'm not seeing the panel described in step 6 with a "Deploy" button. https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/images/deploy.png

What I'm seeing instead is a dashboard that doesn't mention the Mobile Backend Starter at all.  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1HgSE-zL4aHMDlQTV9PaWswUUE/edit?usp=drivesdk

Is the tutorial not up to date? Where can I find a more recent one?

EDIT: This issue is resolved now - Mobile Backend Starter is available in Cloud Console again. https://plus.google.com/+StevePalacios/posts/i4L1iQ7d2XU

Comment: It looks like the Cloud Console is still changing (noticed a few changes from the tuts before) and the most recent one is this. I noticed it about three days ago, and I don't think that there is an updated tut anywhere yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I found the MBS Console:

After a bit of poking around I realized that the App Engine Console (appengine.google.com) provides access to the MBS console, listed under the "Custom" heading in the left hand list of links.

[image: MBS Settings Console link location]

BTW: I needed this to implement the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17495210/549510

Comment: "Mobile Backend settings" is missing from my appengine console...
 https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1HgSE-zL4aHVDFxNzREVW5YR2M/edit?usp=drivesdkhttps://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1HgSE-zL4aHVDFxNzREVW5YR2M/edit?usp=drivesdk

Billing is enabled, project is newly created via cloud.google.com/console

Did you have to do anything to make "Mobile Backend settings" show up?

Comment: Nope, was there without any action on my part. But I do know that Google is running through a few changes in the console. See Brad's comment here: https://plus.google.com/100507164229765455249/posts/i4L1iQ7d2XU