# The mysterious "GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found" error in google appengine / android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

[Code at bottom of post]

I am working on deploying my google appengine backend's datastore, for use in an android application.  I am using endpoints on my devserver and I am trying to "store" standard information - Strings + an integer into my datastore.

When trying to "store" an object at the line "m_suaMyApi.storeBean(...)", I get the
"GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found"
error.

I don't know why this error is being thrown and have been trying for days to locate and correct the issue.

I have tried the following to resolve the issue with no luck so far:

1. Adding a description to the secured-ids section of my app as described here, (after saving) I reverted the app back to open dev and re-saved it.
   [Android Mobile Backend Starter fail with 404 not found... some times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957391/android-mobile-backend-starter-fail-with-404-not-found-some-times)
2. I have made the version of the app that I uploaded "default" as specified in #3 of this problem solving blog post:
   http://kakoma.ug/code/2014/02/android-dev-tutorial-setting-app-engine-connected-app-hiccups
3. I have deleted and redeployed my backend and my app
4. I have shut down my instance and let it reboot and retried my android app.

After these attempts, I am still getting the same error.

At this point I am at the end of my rope and could use some help.

[image: Only My endpoints]

///////////////////////////////

The code that "saves" my object to the endpoint

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {

    private MyApi m_suaMyApi = null;
    private Context m_context;

    private boolean m_debug = true;

    public LoginAsyncTask(String strGoogleUserType, String strGoogleNickName, String strGoogleDisplayName, String strGoogleID,
                          String strGoogleCurrentLocation, int iGoogleCircledByCount, String strGoogleEmail, String strGoogleBirthday,
                          String strGoogleGender, String strProfilePhotoUrl, String strAndroidDeviceId, Date dat) {

        MyApi.Builder builder;

        if (m_debug) {
            builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver, from device
                    .setRootUrl("http://192.168.1.4:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            // end options for devappserver
        }else {
            builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null);
        }

        builder.setApplicationName("myApp");
        m_suaMyApi = builder.build();

        try {

            if (strGoogleBirthday == null){
                strGoogleBirthday = "";
            }
            if (strAndroidDeviceId== null){
                strAndroidDeviceId = "";
            }
            if (strGoogleCurrentLocation== null){
                strGoogleCurrentLocation= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleDisplayName == null){
                strGoogleDisplayName= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleEmail == null){
                strGoogleEmail= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleEmail == null){
                strGoogleEmail= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleGender == null){
                strGoogleGender= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleID == null){
                strGoogleID= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleNickName == null){
                strGoogleNickName= "";
            }
            if (strGoogleUserType == null){
                strGoogleUserType= "";
            }
            if (strProfilePhotoUrl == null){
                strProfilePhotoUrl= "";
            }


            Log.d("myApp", "about to store data");
///////////////BREAKS AT THE NEXT LINE
            m_suaMyApi.storeBean(strGoogleUserType, strGoogleNickName, strGoogleDisplayName, strGoogleID,
                    strGoogleCurrentLocation, iGoogleCircledByCount, strGoogleEmail, strGoogleBirthday,
                    strGoogleGender, strProfilePhotoUrl, strAndroidDeviceId).execute();

            Log.d("myapp", "its stored");
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        // Retrieve service handle.
        MyApi apiServiceHandle = m_suaMyApi;

        return "Login not saved";


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       Log.d("myApp", "LoginAsyncTask: finished");
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The code of my endpoint that the responds to the above

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "storeBeanBean")
    public void storeTask(@Named("strGoogleUserType") String strGoogleUserType, @Named("strGoogleNickName") String strGoogleNickName,
                          @Named("strGoogleDisplayName") String strGoogleDisplayName, @Named("strGoogleID") String strGoogleID,
                          @Named("strGoogleCurrentLocation") String strGoogleCurrentLocation, @Named("iGoogleCircledByCount") int iGoogleCircledByCount,
                          @Named("strGoogleEmail") String strGoogleEmail, @Named("strGoogleBirthday") String strGoogleBirthday,
                          @Named("strGoogleGender") String strGoogleGender, @Named("strProfilePhotoUrl") String strProfilePhotoUrl,
                          @Named("strAndroidDeviceId") String strAndroidDeviceId) {

        DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Transaction txn = datastoreService.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Key UserkBeanParentKey = KeyFactory.createKey("User", "UserBean");
            Entity entUserEntity = new Entity("UserBean", strGoogleID ,UserkBeanParentKey); 

            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strUserType", strGoogleUserType);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strUserName", strGoogleNickName);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strDisplayName", strGoogleDisplayName);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strID", strGoogleID);

            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strUserLocation", strGoogleCurrentLocation);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_iFollowerCount", iGoogleCircledByCount);

            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strUserEmail", strGoogleEmail);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strUserBirthday", strGoogleBirthday);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strUserGender", strGoogleGender);

            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_btmProfilePhoto", strProfilePhotoUrl);
            entUserEntity.setProperty("m_strAndroidDeviceId", strAndroidDeviceId);

            datastoreService.put(entUserEntity);
            txn.commit();

        } finally {
            if (txn.isActive()) {
                txn.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

/////////////
The error reported in my code

```
W/System.err﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.o(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.electrichappiness.allsmiles.forStorage.LoginAsyncTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.electrichappiness.allsmiles.Login.onConnected(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.fg.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.e(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.fg.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.fg.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$b.b(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you running the android application off your phone or an emulator?

Comment: Ive been running it off my phone.

Comment: Can you reach the web-frontend for your application on a browser on your phone?  Also are you trying to hit the local development server or a deployed application?

Comment: im trying to hit a dev server from my phone.  I am using Mavin, with "debuggable" set to true and the phone with debug enabled, and the ip address listed as 0.0.0.0 in the config file.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm running into the exact same exception with my endpoints